# Titanium tableview scrollend event in version 2.1 returns contentOffset position y as 0?

Tags: iphone, events, titanium, listener, tableview

I'm creating a tableview  with pull to refresh for iPhone. I have added an event listener for 'scrollEnd' to get the contentOffset.y. It working fine and return the point value for titanium sdk version 1.8.0, but returns always 0 on pull down the tableview and positive values for pull up the tableview in version 2.1.0

How the get the negative value on pulling down the tableview in titanium sdk version 2.1.0??

Comment: Fixed by using event 'DragEnd'

Answer (score 4):

Define the `offset` variable out of scroll event.
Replace `scrollEnd` with `dragEnd`.
Use the `offset` variable in `dragEnd` event instead of `e.contentOffset.y`.